# i am using twitter bootstrap plugin in my wordpress website to customize the pages,it hides menu in mobile screen

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is my website [clickme](http://www.psqdental.com/shiney)
i’m using bootstrap plugin in my website,when i`m using bootstrap plugin it hides my menu bar in mobile,when i uninstalled bootstrap every thing is working fine,while using bootstrap it appends hide class to my mobile menu,when im trying to remove that class,it is visible even in desktop mode.can any one help me to get out from this situation..THANK YOU..

Comment: thats because in small devices i see the menu div is "menu-toggle hide" please remove the hide class from there in small devices it will work.

Answer (score 0):

yes its overlapping with bootstrap.min.css you have to remove below code at line no. 5 from bootstrap.min.css

```
 .hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and then add custom media query in your theme's css like this

```
@media(max-width:768px){
 display:block;
}
@media(min-width:769px){
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fix for menu issue in mobile**

Please add the following classes instead of hide the classes are inbuilt with bootstap so that there is no need of writing hide class in bootstrap. In the place of hide class replace it with hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm

```
<div class="menu-toggle hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
```

I have tested it. Working fine.

Cheers!